# id or class? dilemma

Tags: jquery, html

There are several tables, where row id - is the number of records in the database, there is a problem. If there are few tables on the page, the id will be repeated. And it's not good, because jQuery does not work correctly because of dublicate id's. 
I only have 2 outputs:

1. Concatenation a first table id's =
   "a_{num}", second table id's =
   "b_{num}"  and that's on...
2. Replace the id to class

But I don't like both of them. Maybe there is a normal solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't really know what you're talking about...

Comment: jQuery is not wrong. It is invalid for the unique identifiers (ids) to have non-unique values.

Comment: jQuery is NOT wrong. `id` is a unique identifier, don't get surprised if things go wrong if you repeat it.

Comment: Hate to contradict you, but jQuery is not wrong. Duplicate ID values for elements is invalid, so technically it is your code that is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 3. Use HTML5 `data-` attributes to store meta data.

Then just set it on the table

`$("table#someId").data("database-records", number)`

Comment: Do this, using `data-*` makes you look pro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need none of them?

Use a selector for all tables, then filter for the number of rows (or whatever you use for displaying the rows..)